# Sherlock Actionbar RTL

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, right-to-left

Android 4.2 introduced the support for Right To Left action bar, is there a way to configure the Sherlock Action bar to be in RTL mode?

note that the current Sherlock Actionbar version is 4.2, but I couldn't find anything related to the RTL support.

Comment: create custom view for action bar

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/actionbarsherlock/HWrZkjcshPg/0vCYNCJLJlwJ

Comment: As far as I know the action bar has yet to be included to the support library.

Answer (score 3):

As of this time, the RTL feature of the ActionBar has not been included in the support library. From what I can gather, it's not scheduled to be, either, since there were some changes to the underlying View structure.

If you're using ActionBarSherlock, it will work the same as if you're using a native ActionBar. From 4.2 up, it will support RTL, and not on lower platform levels. Assuming you have `android:supportsRtl="true"` in your manifest, that is.

If you want to have a good RTL experience for all users, while still using the native RTL support for those on >=4.2, you can check the build level in your app and plan accordingly.

The alternatives as I see it are:

- Use a custom layout for all users and forgo the ease of the new API levels
- Support RTL for no users

Your question was: "Is there any way to configure ABS for RTL?". The answer to that is yes, but only if users are on 4.2. For anything lower than that, there is simply no way to do it without custom layouts.

Comment: Supporting best experience on 4.2 and up, is not an option while ~50% still use 2.3.3

Comment: Agreed, but you can cover both if you plan well. Edited answer.